# Increasing buffer size in setsockopt not reflected during runtime in WIndows

Tags: c++, windows, udp, winsock, winsock2

I've been trying to increase the size of the socket buffers (specifically the receive side buffers for UDP packets) using the winsock2 setsockopt function as such:

```
u_long iMode(1);
handle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP );
int resize = 0;
int intsize = sizeof(int);
int buffersize = 1073741824;
int iResult = setsockopt(handle, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char*)&buffersize, intsize);

if(iResult != 0)
{
    printf("WSACleanup failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
else
{
   printf("Socket rcv buff successfully changed\n");
   getsockopt(handle, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char*)&resize, &intsize);
   printf("New size of receive buff: %d\n", resize);
}
```

During the execution of the program, the printout states that the resizing has been successful and indeed, the apparent value is now the one I've specified. However, I don't notice a commensurate increase in memory usage in task manager on the receive side (Server). However on the sending side I do notice the extra demand for memory (client). I have tried using different machines and playing with the drivers (Mellanox Connectx5), however nothing seems to be helping. I do however notice that the memory fluctuates +/- 200 MBs during the execution of the program, and only once did I notice task manager report that 16 GBs of additional memory were being used.

I have come to suspect that the culprit might be windows RSS technology, and the fact that for whatever reason it seems to refuse to allocate the amount of resources being requested (for the server side only for whatever reason).

I have already tried messing with the registry values (DefaultReceiveWindow and DefaultSendWindow) maxing these two value to 4GBs but that also doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Any help dealing with this issue would be much appreciated as the lack of extra buffering space is significantly impacting the performance of the server side (dropping too many packets, also not receiving fast enough compared to the receive side).

Comment: Changing the receiver's buffer size has no effect on the sender. The receiver can simply buffer more datagrams and not drop them as often. So something else must be going on with the sender outside of this code to make it use up so much memory.

Comment: I'm not sure if I mentioned this, but I change the buffer size of both sides, to ensure that both sender and receiver have enough space to deal with the volume of UDP packets being sent (total rate = 90 Gbps or more)

Comment: I would also like to add that I cannot do this on Linux... and I have noticed weird behavior from RSS (turning it off will ensure that all sender ports send, turning it on allows only some to send), which is why I'm suspecting RSS as being the culprit.